# Pixelated textures Unity with shaders URP

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, blender

I am creating a VR game that is in URP shaders

and I created a cute robot that has face in it, it was made from blender
[This was the robot from blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c318v.png)

and then I exported it as .fbx, and then I imported the robot.fbx into my unity project

then this is the result:
[it has no face](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dsas.png)

I tries placing the face image to the base map of the texture, and this is what happened:
[Squares and pixels texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjf23.png)

this is the materials proerties
[Materials properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRbeb.png)

I was expecting same results with the blender. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Are you using png image format? In that case you may use a different surface type instead of opaque (transparent/cutout).

Comment: Hello Good day @AndoniRivera, yes I am using png format. Is it the format is the problem in my case?

Comment: It is related with the last image you shared. In the surface type property(second porperty), you are defining that is a opaque surface, but what you want to show is a transparent image. See more info about what I refer in Unity documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.0/manual/lit-shader.html